# mock a timeout url

Tags: javascript, timeout

I'm trying to mock a timeout from a webpage so that I can implement a "deal with timeout" feature.

Basically what I need is a URL of something that does not reply within X seconds.

Thanks in advance

Here's the code I have:

```
var req = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"].createInstance();
req.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=utf-8');
req.open("GET", configurationURL, false);
req.variable = specificConfigurationURLTerminator;
setTimeout(function() {
    alert("aborting");
    req.abort();
}, this.configurationRetrievalTimeout);
req.send(null);
```

Comment: Can you not just wrap an AJAX return function inside of a `setTimeout()`?

Comment: @BenM That's exactly what I intend to do but to test it I need a URL that will timeout for sure and that's what I'm after.

Comment: please add the code you're talking about to the question.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Guys thank you so much for your prompt replies. I've found what I was looking for:

http://www.google.com:81/

basically doesn't respond not even with an error =) exactly what I need to trigger a timeout

Answer (score 0):

use .delay(duration) jquery function. duration will be in milisecond. ex- $('div').delay(1500);

Comment: Can't use jquery.. pure java only :(

Comment: @Ricky for java try System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000 this one. may help you

Answer (score 0):

while `www.google.com:81` trick is a good one, it didn't work for me while trying to timeout a `SOAPConnection`, which might be irrelevant.

I happened to have `node.js` installed anyway, and the following did a good job:

First, save the following as `test.js`

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  //res.statusCode = 200;
  //res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  //res.end('Hello World');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Then execute the following in command prompt:

```
node test.js
```

And visit `http://localhost:3000` to hang indefinitely